# Frequently Vs Frequent: adverbial form or adjectival form?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, adjectives, adverbs, derivational-morphology

So normally  adjectives like  *frequent* modify a noun or a   pronoun, whereas adverbs like *frequently* modify verbs or adjectives.

However, in this sentence both options seem fine to me but I couldn't tell which form is more appropriate.

> Sexual Risk Reduction program  is one of the .... implemented programs in college campuses...

Answer (score 5):

*Sexual Risk Reduction program is one of the **frequently** implemented programs in college campuses.*

is the only correct one.

"implemented" is a past participle, a verbal form, even though here it's used attributively.

Now, let's think about the meaning of:

*frequent, implemented program* = program that is frequent and is implemented [kind of strange]

*frequently implemented program* = program that is implemented frequently (in a frequent manner) [makes sense]

Also, search for such combinations at Google Books (not vanilla Google):

["the frequent implemented"](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22**frequently**%20implemented%20programs%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22the%20frequent%20implemented%22) 
0 results

["the frequently implemented"](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22**frequently**%20implemented%20programs%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22the%20frequently%20implemented%22)
About 51 results

Thus the 2nd clearly takes it from this point of view too.

Comment: Although past participles are derived from verbs, they behave like adjectives, the only exception being the *to have* perfect construction, which nevertheless has its roots in that adjectival use.

Answer (score 1):

Still Frequently
though it should either read "most frequently",
or perhaps, to keep it vaguer,

Sexual Risk Reduction programs are a frequently implemented program in college campuses...

or, most concise…

Sexual Risk Reduction programs are frequently implemented in college campuses...